# error after sofware upgrade with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently updated some of the addons for eclipse (3.7). To do so, I started eclipse with sudo (as not doing so caused some errors while installing new Software earlier). Now I get an error immediatly before the splash screen would appear when I start eclipse without using sudo:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2012-09-20 12:27:48.447
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I do not get this error when I start eclipse with "sudo eclipse". Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Cheers
Nebwi

Comment: Do you want to debug eclipse launch?

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess. This could be permission issue.

Did you give permissions to the folders as a sudo. Please right click and see the properties of the files in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter`

And give the read and execute permissions and try. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

While you were "sudo"ing, you may have changed ownership of the files so that you can no longer read them as you.   In a command window cd to you install and type:

```
ls -al
```

If the owner is root, then you will need to change it back to you.   To do this you really need to know your group.  It could be your username, the word "staff", "user" etc.  To find out for sure, just do that same ls command in your home directory.  If you need to change the owners, then type:

```
sudo chown -R yourUserName.yourUserGroup  *
```

On some unix systems it is "yourUserName:yourUserGroup".   Then try eclipse.